LCD screen with extremely narrow field of view
i want to achieve extremely narrow field of view on an arbitrary large LCD screen with arbitrary pixel density
basically i want the image to be visible only if looked at straight on
any slightest tilt of the screen should make the content appear black or invisible
i want to achieve the effect no matter how far/close the person is standing to the screen
any suggestions?

Unless the screen is spherical, concave, and your eye is at the exact center of the sphere, then you will only be able to see, at most one point on the screen "straight on." The line from your eye to every other point will meet the screen at an angle of less than 90 degrees.

Take a bunch of straws side by side. Put them over the screen. You will only be able to see the screen if you look straight down the straws.
